# Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a small problem and I've figured out where when and why it happens but I got no idea how to fix it. The problem is the following :

I have jms:outbound-channel-adapter, gateway and direct channel. And between ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean initialized my adapter and lifecycle activated endpoint I receive a message. So it caused **org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers**

How can I tell my sender bean wait endpoint been activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement SmartLifeCycle and return a phase of Integer.MAX_VALUE. Then, your bean will one of the last to be initialized (CEFB has a phase = 0).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can I make it without SmartLifeCycle? I'm thinking about injecting LifeCycle in my sender as property and start endpoint manually.

Comment: Yes, autoStart = false + manual start should work.

Another option is to implement ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> and use the event to signal that the application context is fully baked.

Comment: thank you for your responses, I choose manual start and this solution works.